# a member of a non managed class cannot have a ref class type or interface class type

Tags: c++, sqlite, command-line-interface

i am trying to implement a gui to a small c++ project, now i am trying to use my unmanaged c++ code in c++/cli in order to use windows forms. after the transform i cannot use the normal sqlite so i am trying to move to the managed sqlite version and i get the error code:
"a member of a non managed class cannot have a ref class type or interface class type" when trying to include a SQLiteConnection in the members of the class.

```
#pragma once
#include <list>
#include "CAlbum.h"
#include "CUser.h"
#include "CDataAccess.h"
using namespace System::Data::SQLite;


class CDatabaseAccess : public CDataAccess
{
private:
    albums _albums;
    users _users;
    SQLiteConnection _sqldb;
    int _lastId;
    CPicture _topTaggedPicture;

    albums _albumsOfUser;
    pictures _picturesOfUser;

    bool fileExistsOnDisk(const string& filename);
    bool initDatabase();

public:
    CDatabaseAccess();
    ~CDatabaseAccess();

    bool open() override;
    void close() override;
    void clear() override;

    // album related
    const albums& getAlbums() override;
    const albums& getAlbumsOfUser(int userId) override;
    void insertAlbum(CAlbum& album) override;
    void deleteAlbum(string albumName) override;
    bool albumExists(string albumName) override;
    CAlbum* openAlbum(string albumName) override;
    void closeAlbum(CAlbum *pAlbum) override;

    // picture related
    void addPictureToAlbum(int albumId, CPicture& picture) override;
    void removePictureFromAlbum(int albumId, int pictureId) override;
    void tagUserInPicture(CPicture& picture, int userId) override;
    void untagUserInPicture(CPicture& picture, int userId) override;
    bool isUserTaggedInPicture(const CPicture& picture, int userId) override;

    // user related
    const users& getUsers() override;
    void addUser(CUser& user) override;
    void deleteUser(string userName) override;
    bool userExists(string userName) override;
    bool userExists(int userId) override;
    CUser* getUser(int userId) override;

    // user statistics
    int countAlbumsOwnedOfUser(int userId) override;
    int countAlbumsTaggedOfUser(int userId) override;
    int countTagsOfUser(int userId) override;
    float averageTagsPerAlbumOfUser(int userId) override;

    // queries
    const CUser* getTopTaggedUser() override;
    const CPicture* getTopTaggedPicture() override;
    const pictures& getTaggedPicturesOfUser(int userId) override;

    // sql related
    void setLastId(char* lastId);
    void resetLastId();
};
```

Comment: What, about the error message, is unclear? You cannot have a managed class member in an unmanaged class.

Comment: my question is how to bypass this error.

Comment: It's simple: Either 1) Make this class managed, or 2) Don't use managed types within unmanaged classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any reasonable way to access (not to say create) managed objects from native c++ code.

But that is not the point. You said you have a c++ program for which you want just a c++/CLI (.Net) GUI. As @AlgirdasPreidžius said you need to decide where to put functionality: in native or managed code, but not mix.

In your case, you need to make clear what is core code and what GUI, and try not to mix. **The core have to be agnostic (not use!) about the GUI**. And the GUI have to acces the core in a very controled form. In this case is convenient to just have pointers to native classes from your core inserted in your managed clases. It "just works". You have to decide if the SQLite belong to the core or to the GUI. The only trick I see here is to acces the data base differently in the GUI and the core: with a "managed" conection from `System::Data::SQLite` used in GUI and a native `sqlite` conection for the native core code. Or, if the managed version can generate a native handle you may pass it to the core code, or create a managed version that take a native conection (if `System::Data::SQLite` have that posibility).

see: [Sqlite3DatabaseHandle](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L49) definition, the [SQLiteConnection::Handle](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L157), and [how it is used to open a conection](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs#L228) and how it [compare with native use](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html).

That said, I had a similar problem (has a c++ program for which want just a c++/CLI (.Net) GUI.) , and it worked good... in my machine. All other machine where I wanted to run my program were protected, I have no admin rigth there and it was always a compatibility .Net version problem which I can't solve. For my needs it was a better solution to switch to [Nana C++ GUI](http://nanapro.org/en-us/). My core code was already GUI agnostic, so the GUI change was not very difficult. Now everything is native code and with static linking the program is an small portable ejecutable than run aeasly in any of my windows machines as a simple user.